# from_tensor_slices() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given Error

Tags: tensorflow2.0

Been tackling a linear Regression problem but I keep getting the same error.

```py
def make_input_fn(data_df, label_df, num_epochs=10, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
    def input_function():
        ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(data_df), label_df)
        if shuffle:
            ds = ds.shuffle(1000)
        ds =ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)
        return ds
    return input_function

train_input_fn = make_input_fn(dftrain, y_train)
eval_input_fn  = make_input_fn(dfeval, y_eval, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)


linear_est = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns)

linear_est.train(train_input_fn)
result = linear_est.evaluate(eval_input_fn)

clear_output()
print(result)
```

```
TypeError: from_tensor_slices() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get accurate answers, you should write what is your target and what problem is making you stuck, attach the portion of code interested and also explain what you've tried to solve the issues

Comment: Change `ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(data_df), label_df)` to `ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(data_df), label_df))`